# Solve Hcaptcha with 2captcha python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, captcha, 2captcha

I am trying to solve Hcaptcha with 2captcha in python selenium
I tried to launch the driver and add 2captcha extension and set it but it's not working

and I tried a lot of codes but no one of them work (and no one of them is selenium)

Comment: Follow the instructions on the 2captcha site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using undetected chromedriver, its basically selenium but with all the flags that selenium left in that expose it as a browser automation tool - hidden. With that, you can simply try clicking on the checkbox (assuming that's the captcha you are getting)

https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver